# getting error in cpanel regarding htacess permission

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cpanel

I have wordpress installed in cpanel and when my error log in cpanel is giving following error.

```
[Mon Oct 11 16:31:35.856159 2021] [core:crit] [pid 24371] (13)Permission denied: [client 209.141.51.176:39184] AH00529: /home/root123/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/root123/public_html/' is executable
[Mon Oct 11 13:12:48.427994 2021] [core:crit] [pid 8707] (13)Permission denied: [client 138.68.249.116:52090] AH00529: /home/root123/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/root123/public_html/' is executable
```

I read all related answers on stackoverflow , they are saying it is permission issue. i changed permission for this file home/root123/public_html/.htaccess  to 775 but issue is still there.

any solution ?

Comment: You don't need to mess up with the chmod if the owner of the file matches whoever is trying to write or execute to it., but 775 should allow anyone to read and execute. What are the permissions of the parent folder?

Comment: i have add on domain in cpanel.   home/root123/ .htaccess   is 644   and /home/root123/public_html/.htaccess is 775 and my domain which is being effected is /home/root123/public_html/domain.com/ .htaccess is 644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files inside a cPanel account should have permissions as **644**, ideally as **640**. **755** is a permission for folders not files (unless you need a file to have the execute permission) which is not the case for .htaccess files.

In general, on cPanel server in **/home/cpaneluser**:

```
public_html should have permissions as 750 and ownership as cpaneluser:nobody
```

All files inside the **public_html** folder should have ownership as `cpaneluser:cpaneluser` and permisions as **750** for folders and as **64**0 for files

So you should check **public_html** permissions and the folders where those **.htaccess** files reside as well.